# Modified `break` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

`break` has signature `[a] -> (a -> Bool) -> ([a], [a])` where the first tuple equals, as I understand, `takeWhile predicate is true`. The second-tuple is the item responsible for making the predicate false plus the remaining list.

```
> break (== ' ') "hey there bro"
("hey"," there bro")
```

But, is there a function that will skip the item responsible for breaking?

```
>foo? (== ' ') "hey there bro"
("hey","there bro")
```

Comment: `break' = (fmap tail .) . break`. That is partial so you want something like `break'' = (fmap tail' .) . break where tail' x = if null x then [] else tail x`

Comment: @user 2407038 Your `tail'` is the same as `drop 1`.

Answer (score 7):

Not in the standard libraries, but you can conveniently `drop 1` on the second element of the tuple using the `Functor` instance for pairs:

```
break (== ' ') "hey there bro"
== ("hey"," there bro")

drop 1 <$> break (== ' ') "hey there bro"
== ("hey","there bro")
```

`<$>` is an infix synonym for `fmap`. Using `drop 1` instead of `tail` handles the case of an empty suffix:

```
drop 1 <$> break (== ' ') "hey"
== ("hey","")

tail <$> break (== ' ') "hey"
== ("hey","*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
```

When working with tuples, though, I generally prefer to use `second` from `Control.Arrow` over `fmap`, because it conveys the intent a bit better:

```
second (drop 1) $ break (== ' ') "hey there bro"
== ("hey","there bro")
```

Comment: Is that lambda character an identifier, a prompt string, or ?

Comment: Prompt. Who doesn’t have `:set prompt "λ "` in their .ghci file?

Comment: @JonPurdy people who are stuck on windows and can't find a terminal emulator they like with decent unicode support =(

Comment: @bheklilr Argh why did you have to say that, of course I had to try it! EVERYONE, DON'T TRY THAT IN WinGHCi, I had to use regedit to delete the prompt setting so I could get it to start again D:

Comment: Come to think of it, I probably could have fixed it easier if I hadn't panicked and closed the window :D

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen You can somewhat get it to work in emulators like Console2 and ConEmu _if_ you're using Cygwin.  The default `cmd.exe` shell has no proper unicode support, so you're just completely out of luck there.  I've had libraries break a `cmd.exe` shell before because I tried `:browse Module.Name` and it used unicode identifiers.  **TL;DR:** no unicode on Windows.