# How can I set my GHCi prompt to a lambda character on Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, unicode, ghc, ghci

I want to have a lambda (λ) symbol as my prompt in GHCi (7.8) on Windows 7, so I set up my `.ghci` file as

```
:set +m
:set prompt  "λ: "
:set prompt2 " | "
```

And I set my console font to Lucida Console since it's supposed to support Unicode, but when I load up GHCi, it looks like this instead

[image: no lambda!]

How can I get Windows to recognize the λ symbol properly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually quite a simple fix, just run the following command before starting GHCi:

```
> chcp.com 65001
```

This sets Window's encoding to the 65001 code page, which lets the λ get displayed properly:

[image]

This will also let a lot of other Unicode characters be displayed properly in `cmd.exe` and other Windows shells (such as Cygwin bash), but Windows' Unicode support is still not perfect, and some fonts don't support many of the characters.  Luckily, λ happens to be a supported character so we can all have the classic GHCi prompt.

Comment: [Ah, memories.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643897/modified-break-in-haskell/23643959#comment36312443_23643959) Still cannot make it work in WinGHCi, though. (Not to mention the command line breaks on the `Ø` in my user directory name.)

Comment: Oh that command line break was just because I didn't change the font.

Comment: Anyway to set this by default?

Comment: @Steve3p0 A solution is given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8).

Answer (score 37):

Using `> chcp.com 65001` worked with GHCi but opening other text files with Vim after setting that encoding returned garbled text.

Add the following to your `%USERPROFILE%\.ghci`. Instead of changing the encoding, you can use the Unicode escaped lambda `\x03BB`:

```
:set prompt  "\x03BB: "
```

If `%USERPROFILE%\.ghci` does not exist, create it first before making the change.

Comment: @vikingsteve: does it work to change the prompt text to anything else? maybe the config is not being picked up, by default it should be located in %USERPROFILE% and named .ghci

Comment: I can set the prompt to any other sort of normal characters, it's just the lambda symbol that isn't working :(

Comment: @vikingsteve: what does the ghci prompt look like when you use `:set prompt  "\x03BB: "` ? It might be the font being used by the console, if it is not true type it displays a question mark instead. With Lucida Console or Consolas it diplays correctly though.

Comment: This answer worked for me, but I had to make a `ghci.conf` in `AppData\Roaming\ghc`. For some reason, GHCi wasn't loading the configuration file when I had it in my home directory.

Answer (score 4):

Using Răzvan Flavius Panda's answer, I decided to make a configuration file that had three flags for setting the prompt. The reason for this is `prompt-cont` is for GHCi versions >= 8.2.0, whereas `prompt2` is for older GHCi versions.

I had a look at [a short tutorial about configuring GHCi](https://typeclasses.com/ghci/config) to try and find out where to put the configuration file. The site says that GHCi reads configuration files in the following order:

1. `./.ghci` (Local configuration file.)
2. Depending on your OS:

   - *nix: `$HOME/.ghc/ghci.conf`
   - Windows: `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\ghc\ghci.conf`
3. `$HOME/.ghci` (Possibly *nix only; didn't work for me.)

I chose the second option.

`C:\Users\Edwin\AppData\Roaming\ghc\ghci.conf`:

```
:set prompt "\x03BB> "
:set prompt2 "\x03BB| "
:set prompt-cont "\x03BB| "
```

Explanation:

- `\x03BB` stands for λ.
- `prompt` is the main prompt. So it'll be "λ> ".
- `prompt2` is for a secondary prompt (I haven't seen it yet). So it'll be "λ| ".
- `prompt-cont` is the same as `prompt2`, and is a replacement for `prompt2` in GHCi 8.2.0.