# "invalid argument" error on win10 when running cabal

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

I am new to Haskell recently, but I am currently facing a very annoying problem:

I followed instructions from [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html), and installed Haskell platform on Windows10 with default settings. But when I tried to run

```
cabal install [package name]
```

to install a haskell package, I always got the error:

```
C:\Users\[My Username]\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc20156_0\ghc_2.rsp: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

Thus, I am not able to install any Haskell packages, which annoys me a lot.

I wanted to figure out a solution to the problem, but I failed. So how can I fix this error? I hope some of you could tell me.

Comment: Unless you did something strange, this is a bug with the haskell platform. You should submit a bug report to them. Meanwhile, you could try using `stack` instead of cabal-install https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Stack seems to be part of the haskell platform nowadays.

Comment: @Cubic This might not be specific to the Platform. [Stack issue #1870](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1870) seems relevant.

Comment: @duplode Ugh, windows and unicode :(

Comment: @Cubic For the sake of completeness: I recently got the same error when I had to build my Hakyll sites (installing packages in general worked fine) on a pt-BR Win 10 machine. I didn't investigate further (not yet, at least) because the `hSetEncoding` workaround in the [Hakyll FAQ](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/faq.html#hgetcontents-invalid-argument-or-commitbuffer-invalid-argument) was good enough for my immediate purposes.

Comment: @Arsenal591 Two things you might try, taken from the discussions linked to above: (1) [In the Control Panel, change "Current language for non-Unicode programs" to "English (United States)](https://superuser.com/a/1199477/320921); (2) [Run `chcp.com 65001` in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27622364/2751851).

Comment: Turns out that works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @duplode can you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Also, @Cubic can you not recommend people switch from the platform to stack for every issue without first investigating, much more commonly it is something else, such as this...

Comment: @sclv Posted. (I didn't do that at first because I hadn't tried all of the workarounds yet -- thanks for drawing my attention back to this.)

Comment: @Arsenal591 Good to know; you're welcome :) I have only seen your reply now, as you hadn't @-notified me.

Answer (score 3):

This very likely is an encoding issue related to the configuration of your OS. When I got the same message on trying to run a Hakyll program on Windows, I found that [running `chcp 65001` in the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27622364/2751851), as suggested by [the Hakyll FAQ](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/faq.html#hgetcontents-invalid-argument-or-commitbuffer-invalid-argument), worked as a workaround.

(Adding [`setLocaleEncoding utf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/GHC-IO-Encoding.html) to `main`, as described there, also helped in my case; that doesn't apply to your situation, though. A reply to the similar-looking [Stack issue #1870](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1870) suggests [changing "Current language for non-Unicode programs" to "English (United States)" in the Windows Control Panel](https://superuser.com/a/1199477/320921); however, doing so made no difference in my pt-BR Win 10 Home system.)