# How can I use mathematic symbols (function name) in the ghci?

Tags: windows, haskell, ghci

I'm learning Haskell. I see an author uses some mathematic unicode chars in the code [here](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell) (`∀` for example). I try use it too, for example:

```
(∀) :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
f ∀ [] = []
f ∀ (x:xs) = f x : f ∀ xs
```

`ghci` loads this sucessfully, but I can't call this function... When I try paste the `∀` symbol into `ghci` console from the clipboard, nothing happens (Windows 7, *Lucida console* font).

It is very convenient - to use mathematic symbols (in my opinion). How can I use it in the `ghci`?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373116/how-can-i-set-my-ghci-prompt-to-a-lambda-character-on-windows

Comment: I did it (`chcp.com 65001`) but this is not help me. The `λ` symbol is displayed sucessfully, but `∀` - not (when I try paste it). Oh, I can't paste the `λ` too via the clipboard... I can print it through my code only...

Comment: codepage 65001 is not UTF8, it just uses the same packing mechanism.

Comment: Is it really more convenient to use mathematical symbols while typing? Especially with cmd.exe that doesn't support copy-paste by keyboard, switching to mouse on every type of that single character doesn't seem really convenient to me. Worse still if you have multiple of them, so you have to switch to mouse, select, copy, back to cmd.exe and paste.

Comment: It seems more compact and more convinient for reading. When I need write a special symbol I do it through the hot keys. For example Alt + 0169 is ©, or Alt + 8704 is ∀. I got used to print special characters through the hot keys. It is convenient for me.

Comment: This seems to work on Mac in it's Terminal: `*Main> (+1) ∀ [1,2]`
`[2,3]`. I suspect this is *windows console* problem, not related to Haskell.

Comment: I found this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-unicode-symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of getting the *visuals* of that is using a font and a text editor that supports [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), like [Hasklig](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig). That way it *looks* like you want it to, but it's saved as a regular ASCII file, which makes it much easier to work with with tools that don't support that technology.

I would recommend **against** using actual non-ASCII characters as identifiers; it might be common in Agda, but it can get simply annoying when trying to work on the same code with multiple people, on different platforms, and so on.

Comment: But I see many matematics symbols in *source codes* in the books too... For example: Richard Bird (University of Oxford) "Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design".

Comment: And I thought that it perhaps is a widespread method naming of functions in Haskell (by mathematicians). When I am reading the books I try its source code too.

Comment: @Bush As long as you want to put your code as an illustrative example in the book, it might be fine. If you want to write actual computer programs that are going to be run, you've yourself noticed that non-ascii identifiers bring in a lot of problems for basically no reasonable gains. And they're harder to type.

Comment: @Bush For real world code, I would suggest not to use unicode symbols. It is certainly not a widespread naming convention and none of the popular libraries in Hackage use them.

Comment: It surprised me that the unicode-font, doesn't support some unicode-characters (The `Alt + 955` works fine in MS Word, but doesn't work in the cmd.exe or powershell.exe, despite Unicode font and code chart).

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying that even when you see mathematical symbols in papers and books about Haskell programs, the original source code is usually plain ASCII text. We use tools like lhs2TeX to apply systematic and hopefully attractive typesetting conventions to produce the rendering of our ASCII code that you see in print.

Comment: Those Unicode problems really aren't so bad on platforms other than Windows, and they should get ever less of an issue in the future. Harder to _type_? I don't really see that in a decent editor, though it's certainly a point in GHCi. Workarounds like Hasklig are cute, but they also bring problems with them (horizontal alignment, bad extendability...). IMO, real unicode identifiers are in many senses more consistent. And you can always supply a `YourModule.ASCII` for compatibility with non-unicode-capable systems, though I agree such redundancy isn't really nice either.